# Javascript: Is it possible to give a "dynamicListener" file access to your main javascript file?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to access my "getUserInput" function from the "dynamicListeners" module I've set up in a different file. Is this possible? Loading "dynamicListeners" into my main file runs it before my main javascript file has a chance to. This makes it so my "getUserInput" function hasn't even been declared yet. I've tried loading my main js file into my "dynamicListener" file but that hasn't worked. What is the correct way to go about this?

index.js:

```
//Loads external modules
const dom = require('./dom.js');
const staticListeners = require('./staticListeners.js');
const dynamicListeners = require('./dynamicListeners.js');


//Main To-do list module
const todoList = (() => {
    const init = function() {

    }



    const createNewItem = function(title, description, dueDate,
        priority, projectName) {
        let newItem = new todoItem(title, description, dueDate, priority,
            projectName);

        console.log(newItem);
        
    }

    const getUserInput = function() {

        let title = document.getElementById('titleBox').value;
        let description = document.getElementById('descripBox').value;
        let dueDate = document.getElementById('dateBox').value;
        let priority = document.getElementById('priorityBox');
        let projectName = 'Default';


        //This creates a new todo item
        todoList.createNewItem(title, description, dueDate, 
            priority, projectName);
    }

    return {
        init,
        test,
        createNewItem,
        getUserInput,


    }
})();

module.exports = todoList;

//Executes external modules
dom.init();
staticListeners.init();
todoList.init();
dynamicListeners.init();
```

dynamicListener.js:

```
//Loads dom module
const dom = require('./dom.js');
const todoList = require('./index.js');

const dynamicListeners = (() => { 

    const init = function() {
        console.log('This is the dynamic listeners init');
        this.eventDelegation();
    }

    const eventDelegation = function() {
        document.getElementById('content').addEventListener("click", function(e){
            let targetId = e.target.id;
            console.log('Ya clicked: ' + targetId);

            if (targetId === 'saveButton') {
                //run function IN INDEX that takes all info from
                //form and creates object, puts it into array
                console.log('UR in the IF...');
                todoList.getUserInput();
                
            }
        })
    }

    return {
        init,
        eventDelegation,
    }

})();



module.exports = dynamicListeners;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just made a new file to hold all of the logic and kept the main one for  actually running everything. This was a dumb question.